# Using two pressure sensors with same address over I2C

Tags: arduino, sensor, i2c, bus, pressure

I'm a novice programmer and I have recently purchased the [SparkFun Pressure Sensor Breakout - MS5803-14BA](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12909) and used it to take pressure readings quiet easily with the sample code provided and an arduino uno. However, I actually need to hook up two pressure sensors to the arduino and get two pressure readings for measuring the pressures inside a pressurised vessel. Does anybody know how I could extend the current example code provided to give two pressure readings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hardware part, look at page 6 of the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/ms5803_14ba.pdf) and move the resistor at the `0x76` label to the `0x77` position on one of the sensors.

> Does anybody know how I could extend the current example code provided
>   to give two pressure readings?

If you're using the library linked to from SparkFun, have a look at [line #39](https://github.com/sparkfun/MS5803-14BA_Breakout/blob/V_H1.0_L1.1.0/Libraries/Arduino/examples/SparkFun_MS5803_Demo/SparkFun_MS5803_Demo.ino#L39) of the code:

```
MS5803 sensor(ADDRESS_HIGH);
```

This declares and initializes a sensor object for the "high" address `0x76` and makes it available via a variable named `sensor`.

Then you can operate the sensor like

```
sensor.getPressure(ADC_4096);
```

So all you'd have to do is to set up another sensor object like

```
MS5803 myOtherSensor(ADDRESS_LOW);
```

and use it like

```
myOtherSensor.getPressure(ADC_4096);
```

to query data from the other sensor (the one with `0x77` ("low" address)).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are two address bits - 0X76 and 0X77.

If you want to read both the sensors just set the address jumper on one sensor. 
So you will get two different addresses from 2 different sensors.

Then just hook up the sensor and from 2 different sensors you will get different output.

[image]

Comment: Note that you'll want to bridge only *one* of the two connections. So on one of the sensors you should *remove* the resistor ("0x76") and use it to connect the other pads ("0x77").

Comment: @chandan:  You need to have your keyboard checked.  It randomly capitalizes words and the . key always seems to double up when you press it.